# How can I access a specific row from a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following variable in R and I want to access 1st and 3rd row having all columns, how can I do it?

```
>Influence
Influence measures of
     lm(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3) :

      dfb.1_    dfb.X1    dfb.X2    dfb.X3    dffit cov.r   cook.d    hat inf
1  -0.007459 -0.002714  6.21e-03  0.010689 -0.03406 1.108 2.96e-04 0.0226    
2   0.167778  0.104486 -2.38e-01 -0.040585  0.31452 1.022 2.45e-02 0.0618    
3  -0.068934 -0.014358  8.54e-02  0.000549 -0.09030 1.389 2.08e-03 0.2189   *
4   0.009435 -0.066932  2.53e-02  0.019826 -0.09097 1.134 2.11e-03 0.0530    
5  -0.048128 -0.082695  1.09e-01  0.244168  0.30123 1.331 2.30e-02 0.2063   *
6   0.015085  0.001275 -1.46e-02 -0.008288  0.03275 1.115 2.74e-04 0.0271    
7  -0.079590  0.091650  1.16e-02  0.050624 -0.19091 1.009 9.07e-03 0.0286    
8  -0.247737  0.090727  2.04e-01  0.034349 -0.29454 1.021 2.15e-02 0.0564
```

When I do write following, I get error as shown:

> Influence[1,1]
>   Error in Influence[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. It can be done as follows:

```
Influence$infmat[c(1,3),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Subsetting didn't work as you expected because `Influence` isn't a dataframe. Verify this with `class(Influence)`.

When you use `Influence$infmat[c(1,3),]` in your solution, you're 1) subsetting to the element of `Influence` called `infmat`, presumably a matrix, and then 2) subsetting that matrix.